# If I had a 1cm iron sphere that I could vibrate at an rate, how fast would it have to be vibrating before it could not perceived by sense of touch?

Tags: frequency, vibrations

Is there a vibratory rate at which my hand would just pass right through the object and it could not be perceived by touch anymore?

Comment: No. You must  have a completely wrong idea of what a vibrating solid is.

Comment: Well, I did say *any* rate of vibration. It's theoretical of course, but if it was vibrating at 100,000 times a second, or 10 million, there's probably a point where the solid cannot be perceived by touch anymore... correct?

Comment: No. Your finger is prevented from passing through the iron sphere by the exchange force, and vibrating the sphere does not affect this force.

Comment: If it was vibrating between your fingers that fast, you'd probably feel that it was touching both your fingers at once. It'd be moving so fast that your sense of touch wouldn't be able to catch up.

Comment: Vibrations are energy, after a certain frequency the ball would melt and your fingers too.

Comment: There's no way that the sphere would pass through your hand (it's still a solid object, even if it's vibrating). However, it's certainly plausible that beyond a certain vibration frequency, the body's tactile senses would fail to pick up the vibration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong here, and if I am, please do correct me. As far as I know the exchange force mentioned above by John Rennie is one and the same as the electromagnetic force, which propagates at the speed of light. Vibrating the sphere at any velocity lower than that of light would not make any difference in being able to detect that it is still a physical object  through the exchange force.

On the other hand, if you could (and you can't) somehow increase the velocity of the sphere to any velocity above that of light, you would have used an infinite amount of energy to accelerate the sphere to this velocity.